# Error while installing packages from expo installing

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, node-modules

I am working on react-native project and while installing firebase using **expo install firebase** and I am getting error continuosly:

```
Installing 1 SDK 40.0.0 compatible native module using npm.
> npm install
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\React-native\new1\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=E:\React-native\new1\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=E:\React-native\new1\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83 --python=C:\Users\HP\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@14.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "E:\React-native\new1\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.24.2 and node@14.16.0 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.15 found at "C:\Users\HP\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.1.29102.190) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.586) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=E:\\React-native\\new1\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=E:\\React-native\\new1\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83" "--python=C:\\Users\\HP\\.windows-build-tools\\python27\\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\React-native\new1\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=E:\React-native\new1\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=E:\React-native\new1\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83 --python=C:\Users\HP\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (E:\React-native\new1\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\React-native\\new1\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd E:\React-native\new1\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-27T11_25_59_406Z-debug.log

npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:439:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at NpmPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:162:31)
    at NpmPackageManager.addAsync (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:105:18)
    at installAsync (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\install.ts:130:3)
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:347:7)
```

I tried **npm i -g windows-build-tools** and **npm install -g node-gyp** as well

but I can't get problems in it..
Can anyone please help me out?

**Node version- v14.16.0
Npm version- 7.6.0
expo version- 4.2.1**

Answer (score 1):

You first need to clear the `npm` cache by using this command

```
npm cache clean --force
```

if it doesn't work then manually delete the `%appdata%\npm-cache` folder.

then update your npm

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

then you can try installing `expo firebase` by this

```
expo install firebase
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## before installing `node-gyp` on windows

```sh
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

## install `node-gyp` globally

```sh
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Comment: this works for me, and open the shell with admin privileges

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the node from the system and then downloaded and installed version 14.15.1 and this issue was resolved